# I get error in apt-get install

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg, aptitude

Recently I m getting the same error when I trying to install with

```
apt-get install -f
```

here after the error:

```
mylinux$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb 
(Reading database ... 237800 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack teamviewer_12.0.71510_i386.deb ...
Unpacking teamviewer (12.0.71510) over (12.0.71510) ...
Setting up teamviewer (12.0.71510) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...



mylinux$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 135 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up ruby1.9.1 (1:1.9.3.551-2bbox1~trusty1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative gem.1.gz can't be slave of gem: it is a slave of ruby
dpkg: error processing package ruby1.9.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ruby1.9.1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: try `apt-get install ruby1.9 --reinstall`

Comment: @RGG I got the following error `E: Internal Error, No file name for ruby1.9.1:amd64
`

Comment: Do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and `sudo apt-get update` then `sudo apt-get upgrade` Is error on above command ?

Comment: @RGG, yes the error is in the command you proposed

Comment: @RGG and I also get error in the command `sudo dpkg --configure -a`. The error is: `Setting up ruby1.9.1 (1:1.9.3.551-2bbox1~trusty1) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative gem.1.gz can't be slave of gem: it is a slave of ruby
dpkg: error processing package ruby1.9.1 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 ruby1.9.1`

Comment: Here two option you have; 1) try to resolve ruby package issue any how 2) move this file as backup `/var/lib/dpkg/status ` and create empty file on there. then update and install any packages